# What I can use to process video sentiment analysis on a video stream?

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I want to make an app,maybe web, that performs a sentiment analysis on a video stream during a web interview.Do you have any recommendations ?
I want to mention that I'm good with java and c#.

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be different for different use cases. You mentioned during web interview. Are you looking for real time processing? How do you capture video - which format? Do you need spoken words analysis or face emotions analysis? And your budget for the same.

Comment: just face analysis, real time

Comment: I came across this site that offers face, emotion analysis in real time on video streams. I have tried their demo on any youtube video - bit.ly/2g7ShS8